# magento set Switch Currency Url

Tags: magento

I have problem with Currency URL.

Suppose my URL is www.example.com/by_women/?color=black
Now i want to redirect same page after change currency.
Here is my code.

---

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
    <span>Select Currency:</span>
    <select name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php endif;
```